# View disappearing when next/previous button is pressed

Tags: iphone, fullscreen, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

I have this very strange problem. I create an `MPMoviePlayerController` in my view controller with the following code:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vid96" ofType:@"mov"]]];
player.fullscreen = YES;
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); 
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
```

Now if the user taps on the next/previous buttons, the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view simply disappears. Is this the normal behavior of `MPMoviePlayerController`? Is there a way to stop this? I don't really need the next/previous buttons, so if there's a way to disable or hide them that would be OK too.

Answer (score 0):

try

[player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlModeHidden];

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  It turns out that there was another UIView in the hierarchy above the MPMoviePlayerViewController.view.

Fixed that and the video stopped disappearing.